# wsdl2java not generating getters and setters on attributes

Tags: wsdl2java

for the following wsdl getters and setters are not being generated for attribute brokerCommission

```
   <complexType name="SplitBackToBackTradeType">
<complexContent>
 <extension base="tns1:SplitTradeType">
  <sequence>
   <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="BrokerIdentifier" nillable="true" type="tns1:OrganisationIdentifierType"/>
   <element name="IntermediateSettlementMethod" nillable="true" type="tns1:SettlementMethodType"/>
   <element name="SourceSettlementMethod" nillable="true" type="tns1:SettlementMethodType"/>
   <element name="IntermediateBookCategoryIdentifier" nillable="true" type="tns1:BookCategoryIdentifierType"/>
   <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="IntermediateCounterpartyIdentifier" nillable="true" type="tns1:OrganisationIdentifierType"/>
   <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SourceCounterpartyIdentifier" nillable="true" type="tns1:OrganisationIdentifierType"/>
   <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="NetGrossConsiderationIndicator" nillable="true" type="tns1:NetGrossConsiderationIndicatorType"/>
   <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IntermediateCurrencyIndicator" nillable="true" type="tns1:CurrencyIndicatorType"/>
  </sequence>
 </extension>
</complexContent>
<attribute name="brokerCommission" type="xsd:double"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I known this is an old issue. but I had a similar problem!

When I was looking at my xsd I found that the extension type had an attribute which was named the same as an element in my complex type.

After renaming the element did the wsdl2java produced getter/setter.